# Тестирование Android JUnit

Tags: android, junit

Решил разабраться, что же такое тестирование. Пару статей на хабре, в Intellij Idea  через Maven  подключил JUnit, посмотрел примеры, написал пару тестовых методов с аннотацией @Test -  все работает.

Потом решил на примере тестового приложения Android сделать то же самое:

1. в build.gradle (Module:app) добавил зависимость

   ```
   dependencies {

       testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

   }
   ```
2. скачал и подключил библеотеку junit-4.10.jar
3. написал такой тест

   ```
   import android.test.ActivityTestCase;

   import junit.framework.Assert;


   public class ChronometrTest extends ActivityTestCase {


   public void testOne(){
       System.out.println(":::::::::::::::::::::testOne() start.. ");
       Assert.assertTrue(true);
   }

   }
   ```

жму правой кнопкой Run/ JUnit test, вот что я получаю в ответ:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/textui/ResultPrinter
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:260)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: junit.textui.ResultPrinter
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 3 more
```

*Android studio v1.2.2

Вопрос: чего я не сделал, или сделал, но не так?

Comment: Попробуйте синхронизировать проект с Gradle: меню Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files

Comment: Стоит заметить, что в текущей стабильной версии Android Studio  (v.1.5) тесты JUnit4 полностью интегрированы во вновь создаваемый проект, включая все импорты, зависимости,конфиги и структуру папок.

Comment: @pavlofff т.е. все то что описано в ответе ниже,  с вот этими зависимостями testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5"
testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0"  -  в Android Studio 1.5  идет уже из коробки, я правильно понял?

Comment: Без `mockito` и `robolectric`, а так - да. Включая папку /androidTest и болванку класса-наследника `ApplicationTestCase`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Актуально для `Android studio`.

Для написания `Unit` тестов использую `Robolectric` и `JUnit4`. `Robolectric` нужен для получения доступа к специфическим для Andoird компонентам, например `Context`.

Для использования `JUnit4` и `Robolectric` надо дописать в `build.gradle`:

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5"
testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0"
```

После чего создать папку `test` рядом с папкой `main`, должна получится примерно следующая структура:

```
app\src\main\
app\src\test\
```

В папке `test` лучше создать такую же структуру пакетов, как и в папке `main`. Хочу заметить что если в обозревателе проектов выбран тип `Android`, то папка `test` не будет видна. Необходимо переключить на тип `Project`. Так же чтобы все `Robolectric` и `JUnit4` классы были доступны необходимо переключить `Test Artifact` в `BuldVariant` на `Unit Test`.

[image: Переключение Test Artifact]

После чего можно начать писать сами тесты. Тестовый класс должен иметь следущющую структуру:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@SmallTest
public class SomeTestClass {

    @Test
    public void someTest(){
        // код, тестирующий что либо
    }

    //остальные тесты
}
```

Для запуска необходимо создать `JUnit` конфигурацию и запускать ее, либо через командую строку. Все юнит тесты будут запускать локально, т.е нет необходимости подключать телефон или запускать эмулятор.

**UPD:** если переключить `Test Artifact` на `Unit Test`, то папка `test` будет видна в типе проекта `Android`.

Comment: Так получилось, все работает. Может подскажите еще где можно почитать спеку по JUnit и  Robolectric ?

Comment: @KirillStoianov начните с официальной документации, которая есть на сайте каждой библиотеки.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно это вызвано неправильным выбором конфигурации: JUnit вместо Android Test

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, данный способ работает, но при этом нужно запустить эмулятор, и строку System.out.println(":::::::::::::::::::::testOne() start.. "); почему то не выводит в консоль! А почему не работает если в конфигурации выбрать JUnit ?

Comment: ```Android Test``` предназначен для тестирования ```UI``` приложения. Для ```Unit``` тестов лучше использовать ```JUnit.```

Comment: @temq В коде используется [`android.test.ActivityTestCase`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/test/ActivityTestCase.html), вот я и подумал, что тест предназначен для запущенного приложения. @kirill-stoianov Попробуйте наследоваться он [`junit.framework.TestCase`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/junit/framework/TestCase.html) и запускать тесты как `JUnit`, если хотите протестировать что-то без запуска приложения. (не уверен, что сработает, но попробуйте =))